# Unresolved reference to a class in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so don't get irritated please.

I have this issue with Unresolved reference in Python. Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db.models import CASCADE


class Post(models.Model):
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author, CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Tag(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I get Unresolved reference (Author) on the

```
 author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author, CASCADE)
```

I kinda realize that it might be a problem with interpreter, but how to solve this? If I'm not mistaken in C++ there is a similar issue, and you solve it by declaring the name in the beginning of a file. How do you do that in Python?

Comment: `class Author` should be defined before `class Post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You classes are not in the right order. At the point where `Author` is used it has not been created so far, because it is further down the code.

Change the order and it should work:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Post(models.Model):
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author, CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the order?

Comment: just asking. out of curiosity

Comment: It [can](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) be put in quotation marks, but that might break some IDE features. If possible try to use the right order.